# Increase the maximum length of HSSFCell in java

Tags: java, poi-hssf

Actually I tried to store some data in HSSFCell using java but i got an error like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The maximum length of cell contents (text) i
s 32,767 characters
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.setCellValue(HSSFCell.java:559
)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.setCellValue(HSSFCell.java:533
)
        at application.ExtractUI.datatoexcel(ExtractUI.java:272)
        at application.ExtractUI$3.getData(ExtractUI.java:208)
        at application.ExtractUI$3.handle(ExtractUI.java:198)
        at application.ExtractUI$3.handle(ExtractUI.java:1)
```

can anyone suggest me a method to increase the cell length ie more than 32767 characters???

I used the following  code for which I got the above error

```
 public void datatoexcel(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            int iter = 0;
            ResultSetMetaData rmeta = rs.getMetaData();
            int col = rmeta.getColumnCount();
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

            Date date = new Date();

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy HHmmss");
            String pa = pth + "\\" + sdf.format(date) + ".xlsx";
            System.out.println(pa);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(pa));
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
            HSSFRow myRow = null;
            HSSFCell myCell = null;
            // Font style for headers
            HSSFFont boldFont = workbook.createFont();
            boldFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
            boldFont.setColor(HSSFFont.COLOR_RED);
            HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setFont(boldFont);
            while (rs.next()) {
                // limit the data to 1000 anad create a new sheet
                if (iter == 1000) {
                    sheet = workbook.createSheet();
                    iter = 0;
                }
                // Adding header to the first row
                if (iter == 0) {
                    myRow = sheet.createRow(iter);
                    for (int k = 1, j = 0; k <= col && j < col; k++) {
                        myCell = myRow.createCell( j);

                        myCell.setCellValue(rmeta.getColumnName(k));
                        // set style to font
                        myCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

                        j++;
                    }
                    iter++;
                }
                // Adding data from 2nd Row
                myRow = sheet.createRow(iter);
                for (int k = 1, j = 0; k <= col && j < col; k++) {

                    myRow.createCell( j).setCellValue(
                            rs.getString(rmeta.getColumnName(k)));
                    j++;
                }
                iter++;
            }

            workbook.write(out);

            out.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

any suggestions??

Comment: Could you add your code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your only option is to switch file formats. There's a hard limit in both the `.xls` and `.xlsx` file formats of 32,767 characters. Apache POI is simply enforcing the file format + Excel limit. You can see details of those limits in the Microsoft documentation, and also captured nicely in [this Apache POI javadoc page](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/SpreadsheetVersion.html)

If you really need text that long, you'll need to switch to another file format such as CSV

Answer (score 0):

Or you can truncate your string length to the specified maximum length minus one

Answer (score -1):

```
private void writeIssueDataForEachRow(Issue issue, Row row, CellStyle style,
                                          List<ColumnIndex> customFieldDefinitions) {
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue(issue.getId()); // 編號
    cell.setCellStyle(style);

    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue(issue.getSubject()); // 主旨
    cell.setCellStyle(style);

    // substring 的原因是要避開 The maximum length of cell contents (text) is 32,767 characters
    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue(StringUtils.substring(issue.getDescription(), 0, 32767)); // 敘述
    cell.setCellStyle(style);

}
```